# Ant - Match all files in a directory

Tags: ant, fileset

I'm trying to copy all the files in a directory using Ant Fileset pattern.

I tried the following,

`**/*` and `**/*.*` but neither of them copies entire directory structure.

Is there any thing wrong in my file set pattern?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are using `fileset` with `file` attribute, it is just for **one single file**.
To copy all the contents of a directory to another, you should use `dir` attribute:

```
    <copy todir="${destination_dir}">
        <fileset dir="${source_dir}"/>
    </copy>
```